# Comparing two columns and highlighting differences in an associated column

Tags: excel, vba

I was recently asked at my job to go through two spreadsheets. Both spreadsheets have an ID column and an associated Rltv ID column, and most of the IDs have more than one Rltv ID. However, something apparently happened that caused us to lose some of our data, so the “2018” spreadsheet has more IDs than the “2019” spreadsheet. Could somebody who is more experienced with VBA help me do the following?

1. Loop through the ID columns and determine if a particular ID has more entries in the “2018” spreadsheet than the "2019" spreadsheet.
2. For any “2018” ID with more entries than the “2019” version, find the “2018” Rltv ID that isn’t present in the “2019” spreadsheet and highlight it.
3. Some "2018" IDs aren't present at all in the "2019" spreadsheet, so those "2018" Rltv IDs need to be highlighted, too.

Here is an example of how I would like the result to look:

2019 IDs and Rltv IDs

[image]

2018 IDs and Rltv IDs

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide. I’m  a web developer in my free time with no VBA experience, and I haven’t had much luck trying to figure out VBA syntax during my limited down time at work.

Comment: You may find it easier as a web developer to put this data into a database and run the queries there. Far easier than learning VBA :)

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question. Generally, you should ask one specific question and have made an attempt to solve it.

Comment: You don't need VBA for this you can use MATCH() and COUNTIF() to do what you need.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and suggestions. I'll talk to my co-workers this week and see which route they would like me to take.